# Accessing variables on Document class from a child class

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

There is a lot of confusion online about this topic, and I am amongst the confused.

Every time I try to change a variable on the Main.as from another class it fails. 
What's worse? I remember doing this in the past in as3.

```
public var mainVar:String = "CHANGE ME"; //on Main.as
```

Types of things I try:

```
MovieClip(root).mainVar = "changed"; //error #1009
parent.mainVar = "changed"; //error #1119
this.parent.mainVar = "changed"; //error #1119
Main..mainVar = "changed"; //error #1119
```

I try to call a function and get similar results using the same language.

Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help.

There have been so many times that it seems like the best idea to store the functions in the class and have them work off the main.as vars once they are called, but I can never find a reliable way to do this, and end up adding children and setting event listeners dynamically, and only working with vars from the main.as. It's easy to do the opposite, changing a var stored on the class from main.as.

Comment: You can make it static, public static var mainVar:String = "CHANGE ME"; then use Main.mainVar = "changed";

Comment: You just need to cast it properly so the compiler knows what kind of object is.  `MovieClip` (what your currently casting root to) doesn't have those properties.   But `Main(root).mainVar` should work

Comment: Changing it to static worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your "problem" is that AS3 is OOP, which means that classes work separately and you need to connect them. The old "way" of doing this (using root) is absolutely wrong when dealing with bigger projects.

There are many ways to do the connection between classes. First, your `Main` class acts like root (if defined as base class through Properties in Flash IDE). So if you create a class that is `DisplayObject` and **add** it to the **main class** (using `addChild();`), then you will be able to do much like before:

```
MovieClip(parent).myFunction();
```

I don't recommend this, but instead more reliable solution - pass the main class to the classes that must use it:

```
var somethingCustom:MyClass = new MyClass(this); // inside Main.as
```

Then in your newly created class save this as a variable and call functions from it:

```
var _root:DisplayObject;
public function MyClass(root:DisplayObject) { // MyClass.as
    _root = root;
    _root.callPublicFunction();
}
```

There are many resources that can help you understanding classes (saying so because this is the normal way they should work):

[How Actionscript 3 Classes Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603993/how-actionscript-3-classes-work)

http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/08/25/tutorial-understanding-classes-in-as3-part-1/

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I will look into your links to see what's happening. Thanks.