# Use my existing function to calculate new values without replacing existing ones

Tags: function, actionscript-3

I've got this code that calculates tides. The function is huge and use the date and the port to calculate it.

There are 4 results :

```
haute1

haute2

basse1

basse2
```

**Now, I'd like to calculate 4 new values** (for date +1) without trigerring the all function with the new date, as it will change the value of `haute1`, `haute2`, `basse1`, `basse2`..
I only want to create new values "`haute1_tomorrow`" with the existing function.

Any idea if it's possible ?

What I was doing was calling the existing function like this :

```
maree("city, tomorrow_date);
```

with `tomorrow_date` as the date of tomorrow. But it would only trigger the function and set new values for `haute1`, `haute2`, `basse1`, `basse2`. 
What I'd like is to keep these values, and create 4 new values `haute1_tomorrow`, `haute2_tomorrow`, `basse1_tomorrow` and `basse2_tomorrow`.

My function (I won't paste the entire function as it would be too long for you to read it) :

```
function get haute1():String { return $pmm; };
function get haute2():String { return $pms; }
function get basse1():String { return $bmm; };
function get basse2():String { return $bms; };

// convenient way to retrieve public data

    function get results():Object
    {
        if (!$pmm) return {}; 

        return {
            haute1:$pmm,
            haute2:$pms,
            basse1:$bmm,
            basse2:$bms,
        };
    }

    function maree($inputport:String = "", $inputdate:String = "", onDataCompleteFunc:Function = null):void 
    {
        if (onDataCompleteFunc != null) _onDataCompleteFunc = onDataCompleteFunc;

        $port_maree = trim($inputport).toUpperCase();   

        /*if ($inputdate != '') $infodate = getdate(date2timestamp($inputdate + " 00:00:00","d/m/Y h:i:s"));
        else $infodate = getdate(date2timestamp(date("dmY") + " 00:00:00","d/m/Y h:i:s"));

        $jour_maree = $infodate["mday"];
        $mois_maree = $infodate["mon"];
        $annee_maree = $infodate["year"];*/

        var $infodate:Array = $inputdate.split("/");

        $jour_maree = Number($infodate[0]);     // 25;      // Day
        $mois_maree = Number($infodate[1]);     // 12;      // Month
        $annee_maree = Number($infodate[2]);    // 2015;    // Year

        loadXmlData();
    }
```

...
..
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **OOP**: **Object-Oriented Programming**.

With no regard to your actual problem, the basic approach to problems like that is making a component/class that is self-sufficient to solve one instance of your problem. For example:

```
package
{
    public class Trigonometry
    {
        public var degrees:Number;
        public var radians:Number;

        public var sine:Number;
        public var cosine:Number;
        public var tangent:Number;

        public function Trigonometry(value:Number)
        {
            // Normalize degrees to -180..+180.
            value %= 360;

            if (value >= 180) value -= 360;
            if (value < -180) value += 360;

            degrees = value;
            radians = value * Math.PI / 2;

            sine    = Math.sin(radians);
            cosine  = Math.cos(radians);
            tangent = Math.tan(radians);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you work with **instances** which are independent and isolated and don't mess with each other's fields:

```
var A30:Trigonometry = new Trigonometry(30);
var A45:Trigonometry = new Trigonometry(45);
var A60:Trigonometry = new Trigonometry(60);
var A90:Trigonometry = new Trigonometry(90);

trace("Sine of 30 degrees is:", A30.sine);
trace("Cosine of 60 degrees is:", A60.cosine);
trace("Tangent of 45 degrees is:", A45.tangent);
```

**UPD**: Then with your task, you need something like that:

```
package
{
    public class Mar
    {
        // Here you need to declare all the variables you are going to use.
        // Like (I don't know what type you need):
        public var $pmm:String;
        public var $pms:String;

        private var callback:Function;

        // Then put all the methods you need:
        public function maree($inputport:String = "", $inputdate:String = "", handler:Function = null):void
        {
            callback = handler;

            // Your processing here.
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use it exactly the same:

```
var M1:Mar = new Mar;
var M2:Mar = new Mar;

M1.maree(/* first call arguments here */);
M2.maree(/* second call arguments here */);
```

So the instances will operate with no regard to each other existence, and you access to their respective fields like:

```
trace(M1.$pmm);
trace(M1.$pms);
```

Comment: And regarding my actual problem, do you see a way to do something similar (or a possible workaround ?)

Comment: @cocoGeek Just do it this way, make it a class with public variables/methods. I updated my answer with some guidelines.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and answer. I must be dumb, as, I'm under the impression that my fonction already is like this. (you can see my full function here [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/10mO293Gf0MN8KCV4JJx39o-Vnk5Q31xc/view?usp=sharing ) I'm under the impression that I could call it like you said with `M1` but it's throwing an error (`Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties`)

Comment: @cocoGeek No, your code is not a class. Your script is the same as any other frame script, it is just put into an external file which you **include** into the frame. Please read the basics about AS3 classes here https://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm or maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603993/how-actionscript-3-classes-work